# Thread pool on a queue in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I've been trying to solve a problem concurrently, which fits the thread pool pattern very nicely. Here I will try to provide a minimal representative example:

Say we have a pseudo-program like this:

```
Q : collection<int>
while (!Q.empty()) {
    for each q in Q {
        // perform some computation
    }
    // assign a new value to Q
    Q = something_completely_new();
}
```

I'm trying to implement that in a parallel way, with `n-1` workers and one main thread. The workers will perform the computation in the inner loop by grabbing elements from `Q`.

I tried to solve this using two conditional variables, `work`, on which the master threads notifies the workers that Q has been assigned to, and another, `work_done`, where the workers notify master that the entire computation might be done.

Here's my C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

std::queue<int> Q;
std::mutex mut;
std::condition_variable work;
std::condition_variable work_done;

void run_thread() {
    for (;;) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mut);
        work.wait(lock, [&] { return Q.size() > 0; });

        // there is work to be done - pretend we're working on something
        int x = Q.front(); Q.pop();
        std::cout << "Working on " << x << std::endl;

        work_done.notify_one();
    }
}

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    std::vector<std::thread *> workers(3);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        workers[i] = new std::thread{
            [&] { run_thread(); }
        };
    }

    for (int i = 4; i > 0; --i) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mut);
        Q = std::queue<int>();
        for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
            Q.push(k);
        }
        work.notify_all();
        work_done.wait(lock, [&] { return Q.size() == 0; });
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        delete workers[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, after compiling it on OS X with `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -o main main.cpp` I get the following output:

```
Working on 0
Working on 1
Working on 2
Working on 3
Working on 0
Working on 1
Working on 2
Working on 0
Working on 1
Working on 0
libc++abi.dylib: terminating
Abort trap: 6
```

After a while of googling it looks like a segmentation fault. It probably has to do with me misusing conditional variables. I would appreciate some insight, both architectural (on how to approach this type of problem) and specific, as in what I'm doing wrong here exactly.

I appreciate the help

Comment: Not your crashing problem: be aware that your access of `Q` in `run_thread()` isn't thread-safe:  `std::condition_variable::wait()` releases the lock when it returns.    Looking at the documentation for the form of `wait()` taking a predicate, I'm not convinced the predicate lambda is executed while holding the lock either.

Comment: The use-case above is a good one for futures & promises (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future).   This solves the problem of packing the result of `work`, which can then be waited on.

Comment: Access to `Q` in `run_thread` is thread safe. When `condition_variable::wait` returns, the lock on mutex is acquired, so these lines `int x = Q.front(); Q.pop();` are safe. Executing predicate in `wait` method is also thread safe too, see documentation http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait, description version with predicate `Note that before enter to this method lock must be acquired, after wait(lock) exits it is also reacquired, i.e. lock can be used as a guard to pred() access.` so access to `Q` in lambda is safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application was killed by `std::terminate`.

Body of your thread function is infinite-loop, so when these lines are executed

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    delete workers[i];
}
```

you want to delete threads which are still running (each thread is in joinable state). When you call destructor of thread which is in joinable state the following thing happens (from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/~thread/)

> If the thread is joinable when destroyed, terminate() is called.

so if you want `terminate` not to be called, you should call `detach()` method after creating threads.

```
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    workers[i] = new std::thread{
        [&] { run_thread(); }
    };
    workers[i]->detach();  // <---
}
```

Comment: Detaching the threads results in the getting disowned by `std::thread` and then leaked. 
Joining them before deleting the `std::thread` means `main()` will wait forever (there are few circumstances where it's a good idea to actually delete the underlying pthread without it competing).  
A better solutions is for each thread to have a flag that can be used as an exit condition, and call detach().

Answer (score 2):

Just because the queue is empty doesn't mean the work is done.

```
finished = true;
work.notify_all();
for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    workers[i].join(); // wait for threads to finish
    delete workers[i];
}
```

and we need some way to terminate the threads

```
for (;!finshed;) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mut);
    work.wait(lock, [&] { return Q.size() > 0 || finished; });
    if (finished)
      return;
```